# HTML 5 classnames and IDs

Tags: css, html

I know that in HTML4 classes and id cannot start with numbers.

I am coding in HTML 5/php and alot of my ids and classes have just numbers in them that point to a primary key in my database for jquery ajax calls.

I cannot find the documentation for HTML5 classes and id spec. Is it valid in HTML 5 to have class and id names such as,

```
class="122"
id="13213"
```

I have ran my output code through w3c conformance checker and all is good, but still I would like confirmation!?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve researched this thoroughly and wrote about my findings: **[The `id` attribute got more `class`y in HTML5](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class)**. From that article:

> HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on [the `id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). The only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters.

To target a classname or ID that starts with a digit in CSS or in JavaScript using the Selectors API, you should [escape them](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes). For example, to target the element with `id="404"`, you can’t just use `#404` — you’d have to [escape it as follows](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0404):

```
#\34 04 {
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what popped up #1 on google when I searched for it! Nice Post! I was just wanting to make sure of it on w3c spec, so I am all ok to carry on?

Comment: @cgwebprojects Sure, go ahead, it’s safe to use. My post links to the appropriate sections of the HTML5 specification. Just remember to escape the ID or class names when you need them in CSS/JS.

Comment: Ye I think I am ok with escaping as well as I am not targetting them via JS but just sending the value of the id via JSON, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The official html5 specs are here: [id-attribute in html5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute).

([Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) you go for html4)

So in html5 the only restriction is **minimum 1 char** and **no whitespaces**.

Comment: Remove the w3fools link and keep the w3c quoting the relevant part here and you get a +1 from me