# loop the .append() with selector as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, append, selector

I am trying to loop the .append() function in order to change the selector each time with different value. But, I don't know the syntax for the selector in order to meet my target. So, how to change it? Thanks so much!
Ka Ho

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=3;
for (var i=0;i<a;i++)                       {                           
$i.append(i);
}
</script>

<div class="0"></div> // expected: display 0
<div class="1"></div> // expected: display 1
<div class="2"></div> // expected: display 2
```

Comment: `class` names should not be numeric values. Use a prefix like "class1".

Comment: @Stefan [Should not be, but can be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210307/html-5-classnames-and-ids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all numeric class and ids are not supported that much as you think it is.

Update your HTML to something like this

```
<div class="box-0"></div>
<div class="box-1"></div>
<div class="box-2"></div>
```

Then you can use the script provided by deadlock in his answer.

```
var a=3;
for (var i=0;i<a;i++) {                           
    $(".box-"+i).append(i); //this is what you need
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a function as argument to `append`, might be cleaner and possibly faster in your case:

```
$('div').append(function() {
    return this.className;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sSVL8/

Comment: its just a newbie question :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=3;
for (var i=0;i<a;i++)                       {                           
$("."+i).append(i); //this is what you need
}
</script>

<div class="0"></div> // expected: display 0
<div class="1"></div> // expected: display 1
<div class="2"></div> // expected: display 2
```

Comment: @user2108245 a new question should be posted separately.