# hasClass and condition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, this isn't launching

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
if ($(h3).hasClass("6") ){
alert ('Todays Date Friday')  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that `.hasClass()` will only look at the first `<h3>` found and return whether **that one** has the class "6"

Comment: And you have no idea why?  Did you take a look at your error console?

Answer (score 5):

```
$(h3)
```

supposed to be

```
$('h3') // Missing the quotes
```

If you want your selector to work, you can assign the variable name.

```
var h3 = 'h3'; // This should   work as well
if ($(h3).hasClass("6") ){
```

Comment: This. And as for the class called `6`, read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/684932 CSS classes can't start with number.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL.. It is not essentially invalid. But it is a better practice to avoid using class names that start with a number

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Yes they can. People just need to learn how to use selectors properly

Comment: @RaphaelDDL [I would disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210307/html-5-classnames-and-ids).

Comment: Having a class name starting with a number is valid `HTML` , but the styles might not be added for such cases using `CSS`

Comment: Forgot HTML5 removed that HTML4/xHTML restriction. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Sushanth-- There should be no problem having styles added, they just need to be escaped. http://jsfiddle.net/JszJ9/