# CSS syntax, how to use li.class:hover?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply a class to a li element but when hover event ^^

I'm ok without the class with this code :

```
#leaderboard li:hover {
    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-transform: scale(3.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(3.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(3.2);
    -o-transform: scale(3.2);
    transform: scale(3.2);    
}
```

But when I try like that, that's nok ok :

```
#leaderboard li.0:hover {
    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);    
}
```

Html here :

```
<ul id="leaderboard" name="leaderboard">
<li class="0" style="left: 0px;"><h1 style="display:inline" id="user-234">4900</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="serveurtopmc.jpg"> xxx</li>
<li class="1" style="left: 440px;"><h1 style="display:inline" id="user-836">4090</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="banniere_1000x240.jpg"> xxx</li>
<li class="2" style="left: 770px;"><h1 style="display:inline" id="user-590">3488</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="9.gif"> xxx</li>
<li class="3" style="left: 770px;"><h1 style="display:inline" id="user-1">2556</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="coeur.png"> xxx</li>
<li class="4" style="left: 880px;"><h1 style="display:inline" id="user-546">2542</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="1372878266-photo15.jpg"> xxx</li>
<li class="5" style="left: 440px;"><h1 style="display:inline" id="user-597">2536</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="logo.png"></li></ul>
```

Someone have the right syntax please ? :)

==========

I did it and just finished to test it (it was a bit long because the number was generated by a jscript) That's work perfectly => #leaderboard li.rank0:hover { Thanks mcabrams :)

Comment: hi Wolwx, could you post your html please?

Comment: What is `.0`? Class names shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: Class identifiers are allowed to start with a number. ID's on the other hand cannot.

* Edit: apparently both will actually work this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210307/html-5-classnames-and-ids

Comment: Hi ArtyMcFly :)

html updated on main post

Comment: From the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters): *In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit**. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".*

Comment: That is from the CSS2 spec.

Comment: Exact Hashem Qolami, that's was my weak point ^^' Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try targeting the selector as `#leaderboard li.\30:hover` - this utilizes unicode's representation of the number 0 (\30 -> 0). If you wanted to to the same rule for the 10 class, it would be `#leaderboard li.\31\30:hover`. Another approach is changing the class to a name that does not begin with a number.

Sources:

- [HTML 5 classnames and IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210307/html-5-classnames-and-ids)
- http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not working :x
#leaderboard li.\0:hover
#leaderboard li.\1:hover

Comment: Have you tried changing the class to a name that does not begin with a number? i.e. `leaderboard-1`, and changing the CSS accordingly?

Comment: I did it and just finished to test it (it was a bit long because the number was generated by a jscript)

That's work perfectly =>
#leaderboard li.rank0:hover {

Thanks mcabrams :)

Answer (score 2):

If the class needs to remain a number, you can escape the Unicode code point for 0: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcwVN/1/)

```
#leaderboard li.\30:hover {
    color: coral;
}
```