# Using variables in place of calling jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors, concatenation

```
var container = $("#container");
var row = $(".row");
container.append("<button>CLEAR SCREEN</button>");

for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
container.append("<div class='row " + i + "'></div>");

for (j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
$(".row." + i).append("<div class='cell " + j + "'></div>");
}
}
```

I would like to change out $(".row.") with a variable so that I'm not calling it on every loop and can't seem to get it to work right. I tried - (row + "." + i).append... but that didn't work.

Comment: Is the second dot in `$(".row." + i).append(` a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo, it's a string he is trying to append.

Comment: Classnames must not start with a number! See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210307/html-5-classnames-and-ids .
"To target a classname or ID that starts with a digit in CSS or in JavaScript using the Selectors API, you should escape them."

Answer (score 2):

Select all rows before doing the loop and just filter the result inside the loop.

```
var row = $(".row");

...

for (j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
    row.filter("." + i).append("<div class='cell " + j + "'></div>");
}
```

**Edit:** Okay, I missed that the rows get created in the first loop, so naturally they are not avalable for selection before that and selections don't get updated. Thus, instead of selecting the rows, I suggest you save a reference to the row on creation and use that:

```
var container = $("#container");
container.append("<button>CLEAR SCREEN</button>");

for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    $row = $("<div class='row " + i + "'></div>");

    for (j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
        $row.append("<div class='cell " + j + "'></div>");
    }
    container.append($row);
}
```

Comment: This works when I initialize within the first for loop just before the second for loop. If I try to initialize it outside of either loop, it doesn't work. Is that because there are now rows yet created?

Answer (score 0):

How about this. I believe you want that period in there?

```
for (j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
    row.add("." + i).append("<div class='cell " + j + "'></div>");
}
```